# how to build a dual language webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to design a dual language webpage i.e in English and Kannada. I don't want  to load a new webpage or reload the page as the user switches between the languages.Please let me know if there is any solution using JavaScript or PHP

Comment: implement google translator script. https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs

Comment: You surely don't expect anyone to start spitting out the myriads of options that exist..

Comment: I don't want to translate the content, I just want to load the content in another language.

Comment: that is called translation, i think you have different written the content in both languages, `AJAX` have you heard about it ? use that.

Comment: You are probably wanting to localize your website..Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754520/what-is-the-actual-differences-between-i18n-l10n-g11n-and-specifically-what-does

Comment: You can use Jquery fadeIn() faedeOut() functions, to Hide and Show the already translated versions as user switches the language

Comment: You can use `gettext` http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we need to do is to create a couple of files that will contain the text for each of the languages that will be supported by the website. For demo purpose I have chosen English, Spanish and German.

Make a directory named “directory”. In this directory create 3 files:

- lang.de.php
- lang.en.php
- lang.es.php

In our main file (index.php) we will include a file (common.php) containing a piece of code that gets the requested language.

Here’s the content for 3 language files.

lang.en.php:

```
<?php
/*
  ------------------
  Language: English
  ------------------
 */

$lang = array();

$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'My website page title';
$lang['HEADER_TITLE'] = 'My website header title';
$lang['SITE_NAME'] = 'My Website';
$lang['SLOGAN'] = 'My slogan here';
$lang['HEADING'] = 'Heading';

// Menu

$lang['MENU_HOME'] = 'Home';
$lang['MENU_ABOUT_US'] = 'About Us';
$lang['MENU_OUR_PRODUCTS'] = 'Our products';
$lang['MENU_CONTACT_US'] = 'Contact Us';
$lang['MENU_ADVERTISE'] = 'Advertise';
$lang['MENU_SITE_MAP'] = 'Site Map';
?>
```

lang.es.php:

```
 <?php
/*
 -----------------
 Language: Spanish
 -----------------
 */

$lang = array();

$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'Título de la página de mi sitio web';
$lang['HEADER_TITLE'] = 'Mi sitio web de la cabecera título';
$lang['SITE_NAME'] = 'Mi Sitio Web';
$lang['SLOGAN'] = 'Mi lema aquí';
$lang['HEADING'] = 'Título';

// Menu

$lang['MENU_HOME'] = 'Inicio';
$lang['MENU_ABOUT_US'] = 'Sobre Nosotros';
$lang['MENU_OUR_PRODUCTS'] = 'Nuestros productos';
$lang['MENU_CONTACT_US'] = 'Contáctenos';
$lang['MENU_ADVERTISE'] = 'Publicidad';
$lang['MENU_SITE_MAP'] = 'Mapa del Sitio';
?>
```

lang.de.php:

```
 <?php
 /*
  -----------------
  Language: German
  -----------------
  */

 $lang = array();

 $lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'Meine Webseite Titel';
 $lang['HEADER_TITLE'] = 'Meine Website-Header Titel';
 $lang['SITE_NAME'] = 'Meine Website';
  $lang['SLOGAN'] = 'Mein Slogan hier';
 $lang['HEADING'] = 'Position';

 // Menu

 $lang['MENU_HOME'] = 'Heim';
 $lang['MENU_ABOUT_US'] = 'Über uns';
 $lang['MENU_OUR_PRODUCTS'] = 'Unsere Produkte';
 $lang['MENU_CONTACT_US'] = 'Kontaktieren Sie uns';
 $lang['MENU_ADVERTISE'] = 'Werben';
 $lang['MENU_SITE_MAP'] = 'Site Karte';
 ?>
```

Analyzing the common.php file:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

 if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
 {
 $lang = $_GET['lang'];

 // register the session and set the cookie
 $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

 setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
 }
 else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
 {
 $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
 }
 else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
 {
 $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
 }
 else
 {
  $lang = 'en';
 }

  switch ($lang) {
  case 'en':
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
   break;

  case 'de':
  $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
  break;

  case 'es':
    $lang_file = 'lang.es.php';
  break;

 default:
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';

 }

 include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
 ?>
```

The constants values should be outputted in the page. Examples; for document title:

```
  <title><?php echo $lang['PAGE_TITLE']; ?></title>
```

For header menu:

```
 <ul>
 <li><a href="/"><?php echo $lang['MENU_HOME']; ?></a></li>
 <li><a href="about_us"><?php echo $lang['MENU_ABOUT_US']; ?></a></li>
 <li><a href="our_products"><?php echo $lang['MENU_OUR_PRODUCTS']; ?></a> 
</li>
 <li><a href="contact_us"><?php echo $lang['MENU_CONTACT_US']; ?></a></li>
 <li><a href="advertise"><?php echo $lang['MENU_ADVERTISE']; ?></a></li>
 <li><a href="sitemap"><?php echo $lang['MENU_SITE_MAP']; ?></a></li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just have a look at this,
Make two classes for your languages, say English and Kannada.
In your layouts, keep the second language division next to the first language division. But don't display both. So this should be repeated for every content of your webpage.
I think this is what you want.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title of the document</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanskannada.css);



 #header
 {
 padding:10px;background:#484848;color:#EDEDED;text-allign:center;width:100%;font-size:25px;
 }
 .kannada,.english
 {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:20px;font-size:20px;
 display:none;
 }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     $('.english').fadeIn(1000);
     $('.kannada').fadeOut(500);
 });


 function changeLang()
 {
     var language = document.getElementById('change').innerHTML;
     if(language === "Kannada")
     {
         $('.english').fadeOut(500);
         $('.kannada').fadeIn(1000);
         document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = "English";
     }
     else if(language === "English")
     {
         $('.kannada').fadeOut(500);
         $('.english').fadeIn(1000);
         document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = "Kannada";
     }

 }
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="header"><font style="font-size:18px;color:#FFFFFF;">Load in : &nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span id="change" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="changeLang();">Kannada</span></div>
 <div class="english"><p>This is the paragraph in English</p></div>
 <div class="kannada"><p>ಈ ಪ್ಯಾರಗ್ರಾಫ್ ಕನ್ನಡದಲ್ಲಿ ಇದೆ.</p></div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Both language contents will be rendered in the same page when the page loads. But only the selected language will be displayed to the user. When he switches to another language, current content will be hidden, and hidden content will be displayed.

Comment: You’ll also want [`lang` attributes](https://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#the-lang-and-xmllang-attributes) on the `<div>`s, to indicate which language they’re in in a way that browsers and screen readers and such can understand.