# What is the relation between Locale and ResourceBundle

Tags: java, localization, internationalization

Can someone please explain what is the relation between Locale and ResourceBundle classes provided by the JDK ?  Is it the same as the  [difference between i18n vs l10n as given  in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506752/1527084) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between Locale and ResourceBundle is, Locale is used to read the right properties file. Basically, the ResourceBundle.Control class takes a Locale object, and given the base name of the properties file, it tries to find the best matching one. For example:

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getbundle("messages", Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-TW");
```

If you do that, the ResourceBundle.Control will look for messsages_zh_TW.properties, messages_zh-Hant-TW.properties, messages_zh-Hant.properties, messages_zh.properties and finally fall-back to messages.properties if it cannot find any of the specific resource file.

**EDIT**

Just to add one final thing. If you omit the Locale parameter, the `ResourceBundle.getBundle(String)` will return the properties file based on your default Locale - the one that you can obtain like this:

```
Locale default = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY);
```

Although it might seem unnecessary of excessive typing (in the context of desktop applications), it is a good practice to always pass the Locale, as it makes code easier to understand.