# My team is doing localization automation using Selenium. How to do the localization testing using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

My team is doing localization automation using Selenium. How to do the  localization testing using selenium web driver

Comment: That's not nearly precise enough to elicit an answer. I suggest you read: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n or http://stackoverflow.com/q/506743/954442 or perhaps http://www.welocalize.com/plan-software-localization-testing-strategy/ and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience testing localization, you should implement a translated locate key e.g XY.
Using selenium you can verify that all elements/text on site are localized using the XY String.

The XY String can be any language translated locale string.

Hope this helps